# Jersey 2.22: What is the default connect timeout for Client?

Tags: java, jersey, timeout, client

I tried:

`client.getConfiguration().getProperty(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT)`

but it just returned a `null`.

I was wondering what the default time out is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientProperties.html#CONNECT_TIMEOUT):

> The default value is infinity (0).